# How do I access JSON.stringified data which is sent over AJAX in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am creating data in JavaScript which I want to send as an object over AJAX and then access its content in PHP. I have tried so many approaches that I found online but none of them seem to give me more than an empty result in PHP.

Here is my code on the JS side:

```
myData = {};
myData['a'] = ["1", "2"];
myData['b'] = "3";

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: my_ajax_site_url,  
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        action: "my_php_function",
        inputData: JSON.stringify(myData),
    },
    success: function(response) { 
    },
});
```

JSON.stringify(myData) gives me the following result when I console.log:

```
{"a":["1", "2"],"b":"3"}
```

Then on the PHP side I have tried to access the data through e.g. json_decode like this:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['inputData']);
$a = $data['a'];
```

But `$a` is always empty.

If I send just a string as `inputData` I can then easily access it as `$a = $_POST['inputData']` and `$a` then gives me that string. So I know it goes to the function correctly and it works in the general case. I just can't seem to grasp how to do it with an object.

**How can I send my JS object/JSON string over AJAX and access it in PHP? **

Comment: Try `json_decode($_POST['inputData'], true);`. Passing `true` as the second argument will return the JSON object as an array. If you omit it, you'll get an object back and then need to access the data like this: `$data->a` instead of `$data['a']`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong. Apparently `$_POST['inputData']` gets backslashes to its double quotes which made json_decode fail. The string in PHP looks like this instead:

```
{\"a\":[\"1\", \"2\"],\"b\":\"3\"}
```

I first had to remove all backslashes, json_decode and then access it like @M.Eriksson said in the comments:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['inputData']));
$data->a;
```

Comment: PHP generally **won't** do that under normal circumstances. It will if you have Magic Quotes turned on, but you can't turn it on in PHP 5.4 (which hit end of life in 3 Sep 2015 ) or newer. This suggests you are using a **horribly** out of date and insecure version of PHP that you desperately need to upgrade.

Comment: @Quentin, No I use PHP 8.something.